# Logging VPN Traffic (L2TP/IPSec on Ubuntu)

Tags: vpn, logging, ipsec, ppp, l2tp

I'm running a small, private VPN server for me and 2-3 other people. For bandwidth monitoring, and to comply with any possible DMCA or other government (re: new Canadian law) requests, I want to have a log of authentications by user, and the users' activities (traffic aka addresses visited, not private login data or session info). Is there a way to log traffic by user when connected to the VPN?

My goal in running a VPN server is not to evade legitimate sources-- it's just to protect my data a bit in a cafe / while traveling. I'm not trying at all to make this a private service as only a few close friends + family members use it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but the functionality depends on your set up.

Which VPN server and on what OS are you running it on? I can amend my answer if you provide the info, that way I can replicate your set up.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Ubuntu, openswan, and xl2tpd using ppp. I think that's all the info that would be relevant? Thanks for any guidance!